# Why do black holes remain?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, event-horizon, singularities

When we think about black holes as not containing matter but being regions of warped spacetime, I can't think why they don't revert to being Euclidian space more quickly. This is because I can see how a collapsing star might do the work to warp spacetime so severely but once that energy dissipates, why does the spacetime stay warped?

Comment: Re, "When I bend an iron rod, ... I force atoms to decay." Actually, you only cause atoms to change their positions within the rod. You don't do anything that alters the integrity of the atoms themselves. See https://yenaengineering.nl/what-is-plastic-deformation-in-metals/

Comment: The first paragraph with the actual question seems fine, but the second paragraph should be edited to remove the weird and unnecessary hypothesis that "atoms... decay" when you bend an iron rod. You can just ask your question without including an unnecessary and factually inaccurate example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> warp spacetime so severely but once that energy dissipates

What do you mean by "once that energy dissipates"? If the energy equivalent to the mass of the star dissipated completely, there won’t be any black hole — no mass, no black hole. If the star formed a black hole eventually, the energy obviously didn’t get dissipated much, thus space still got warped as it should be.

On the other hand, when you bend an iron rod, you would not be doing anything to the atoms, it would just be the rearrangement of the molecules. Therefore, banding an iron rod would not have anything to do with the decay of atoms nor spacetime.

Comment: I see. So, the energy in the star 'translates' into warped spacetime, rather than creates warped spacetime. This has helped my understanding. Thank you.